# Agregar datos en un estado de redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

lo que quiero lograr es sencillo, quiero recibir un texto y agregarlo al estado de redux. Si bien recibo el texto (a travez de un input) se reemplaza por el texto anterior y yo no quiero que suceda.

```js
// constantes
const dataInicial = {
    array: []
}

const OBTENER_NOMBRE = 'OBTENER_NOMBRE'

// reducer
export default function reducer(state = dataInicial, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case OBTENER_NOMBRE:
            return {...state, array: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

// acciones
export const obtenerNombre = (nombre) => (dispatch,getState) =>{

    try {
        dispatch({
            type: OBTENER_NOMBRE,
            payload: nombre
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Creo que el problema esta en "return {...state, array: action.payload}" pero no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: si quieres recuperar los datos del store tienes que seleccionarlos con un selector. Y no usar el dispatch. https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude solucionarlo, solamente cambie la data inicial por un array vacio y en el return puse "return [...state, action.payload]"

Queda de la siguiente manera

```js
// constantes
const dataInicial = []

const OBTENER_NOMBRE = 'OBTENER_NOMBRE'

// reducer
export default function reducer(state = dataInicial, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case OBTENER_NOMBRE:
            return [...state, action.payload]
        default:
            return state
    }
}

// acciones
export const obtenerNombre = (nombre) => (dispatch,getState) =>{

    try {
        dispatch({
            type: OBTENER_NOMBRE,
            payload: nombre
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```